# Does granting cancan ability to create automatically imply access to new action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have a cancan ability that says a user can `create` a `Message` if it's theirs

```rb
can [:create], [Message] do |message|
  message.user_id == user.id && message.conversation.sender_id == user.id
end
```

This works as expected, but, surprisingly, this rspec test for whether the user can access the `new` action for a message fails:

```rb
it 'A user should not be able to access their own message new action' do
  expect(ability).to_not be_able_to(:new, message)
end
```

So the user ***can*** access the `new` action for their message. Why is this? Does access to the `create` action somehow imply access to `new` as well? Or have I misinterpreted or made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `:new` is an alias of `:create`

See here:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Action-Aliases